# How can we do a sentiment analysis and create a 'sentiment' record next to each line of text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I Googled for some solutions to do sentiment analysis, and write the results to a column next to the column of text that's being analyzed. This is what I came up with.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('punkt')

# first, we import the relevant modules from the NLTK library
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

# next, we initialize VADER so we can use it within our Python script
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

# the variable 'message_text' now contains the text we will analyze.
message_text = '''Like you, I am getting very frustrated with this process. I am genuinely trying to be as reasonable as possible. I am not trying to "hold up" the deal at the last minute. I'm afraid that I am being asked to take a fairly large leap of faith after this company (I don't mean the two of you -- I mean Enron) has screwed me and the people who work for me.'''

print(message_text)

# Calling the polarity_scores method on sid and passing in the message_text outputs a dictionary with negative, neutral, positive, and compound scores for the input text
scores = sid.polarity_scores(message_text)

# Here we loop through the keys contained in scores (pos, neu, neg, and compound scores) and print the key-value pairs on the screen
for key in sorted(scores):
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='')
```

This gives me:

```
compound: -0.3804, neg: 0.093, neu: 0.836, pos: 0.071,
```

Now, I am trying to feed in my own column of text, from a dataframe.

The sample code is from this site.

https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/sentiment-analysis

I have a field in a dataframe that consists of text, like this.

```
These brush heads are okay!  Wish they came in a larger diameter, would cover more facial surface area and require less time to do the job!  However, I think they do a better job than just a face cloth in cleansing the pores.  I would recommend this product!
No opening to pee with. weird.  And really tight.  not very comfortable.
I choose it as spare parts always available and I will buy it again for sure!I will recommend it, without doubt!
love this cleanser!!
Best facial wipes invented!!!!!!(:
```

These are 5 individual records from my dataframe. I'm trying to think of a way to assess each record as 'positive', 'negative', or 'neutral', and place each sentiment in a new field in the same row.

In this example, I would think these 5 records have the following 5 sentiments (in a field next to each record):

```
neutral
negative
positive
positive
positive
```

How can I do that?

I came up with an alternative sample of code, as shown below.

```
event_dictionary ={scores["compound"] >= 0.05 : 'positive', scores["compound"] <= -0.05 : 'negative', scores["compound"] >= -0.05 and scores["compound"] <= 0.05 : 'neutral'} 
#message_text = str(message_text)
for message in message_text:
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(str(message))
    for key in sorted(scores):
        df['sentiment'] = df['body'].map(event_dictionary)
```

This ran for about 15 minutes, then I cancelled it, and I saw that it actually did nothing at all.  I want to add a field named 'sentiment' and populate it with 'positive' if scores["compound"] >= 0.05, 'negative' if scores["compound"] <= -0.05, and 'neutral' if scores["compound"] >= -0.05 and scores["compound"] <= 0.05.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to do a simple sentiment analysis of a single field in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121537/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-simple-sentiment-analysis-of-a-single-field-in-a-datafram)

Comment: My question remains the same as the one on the previous (identical) question: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? The accepted answer is just a loop, and three lines of code whose functionality is given by the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this dataframe looks like, but you can use the Sentiment Intensity Analyzer on each of the strings to calculate the polarity scores of each message. According to the github page, you can use the "compound" key to calculate the sentiment of a message.

https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment#about-the-scoring

```
messages = [
"These brush heads are okay!  Wish they came in a larger diameter, would cover more facial surface area and require less time to do the job!  However, I think they do a better job than just a face cloth in cleansing the pores.  I would recommend this product!",
"No opening to pee with. weird.  And really tight.  not very comfortable.",
"I choose it as spare parts always available and I will buy it again for sure!I will recommend it, without doubt!",
"love this cleanser!!",
"Best facial wipes invented!!!!!!(:"]

for message in messages:
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(message)

    for key in sorted(scores):
        print('{0}: {1} '.format(key, scores[key]), end='')

    if scores["compound"] >= 0.05:
        print("\npositive\n")

    elif scores["compound"] <= -0.05:
        print("\nnegative\n")
    else:
        print("\nneutral\n")
```

**Output:**

```
compound: 0.8713 neg: 0.0 neu: 0.782 pos: 0.218
positive

compound: -0.7021 neg: 0.431 neu: 0.569 pos: 0.0
negative

compound: 0.6362 neg: 0.0 neu: 0.766 pos: 0.234
positive

compound: 0.6988 neg: 0.0 neu: 0.295 pos: 0.705
positive

compound: 0.7482 neg: 0.0 neu: 0.359 pos: 0.641
positive
```

Comment: Actually, when I look at this closer, everything is coming out positive.  Something is wrong here.  I tried this: if scores[key] >= 0.05: That makes everything positive.  I tried this: if scores["compound"] >= 0.05: That makes everything positive too.  I can see the print statement printing some 'negative' and some 'neutral'.  I think the logic is very close, but something is definitely off here.  What prints out is NOT the text that is assigned to my 'sentiment' field in my dataframe: if scores[key] <= -0.05:
            df['sentiment'] = 'negative'

Comment: `df['sentiment'] = 'negative'` I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but that assigns the value `'negative'` to the entire column.

Comment: But, again, everything is labeled as 'positive'.  I think there is a simple fix for this, but I'm not sure what it is.  This is my first foray into NLP using Python.  Thoughts?  Comments?  Suggestions?  I am open to any and all.  Thanks.

Comment: I just made a small change to my original post.  Does that clear things up?  Does it make sense now?